# Bind Ip not working in mongod.conf file

Tags: mongodb

I want to add protection like no one can access mongodb database outside the ip address that mention in bindIp mongod.conf file.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,110.3.4.453
```

I have added Ip address like mention in above but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrappin up your ips with []
like `bindIp: [127.0.0.1,110.3.4.453]`. I am using version 3.2.0 and this is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried it and restart the mongodb server but not working for me.

Comment: May be try it with `=` sign  instead of `:`.

Comment: What's not working by the way.. connecting locally or from remote?

Comment: In mongod.conf file all setting assign by : ( colon ) not = ( equal to ) so it will not work. I am trying to connecting database from external ip address and it connected

Comment: it will not work ?? did you try it.  I expect this to work and by the way you can configure firewall to restrict the connection to certain ips. you can read more here https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/   good luck

Comment: Works for me `[127.0.0.1,110.3.4.453] ` on MongoDB 3.4 - Don't use `=` instead of `:`!